# Triggering jobs with specific branch names( pattern) in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a set of jobs that needs to be triggered only when branches are named by certain pattern. (Eg: ctl-sw-v01.01.01-vbeta,  ctl-sw-v01.11.01-vbeta, ctl-sw-v11.01.01-vbeta, ctl-sw-v01.01.21-vbeta). To make this generic, I have a pattern developed using regex `'~ /^ctl-sw-v\d+\.\d+.\d+(-vbeta)?$/'`. But I am finding it confusing as to how to specify this in the variables section in the yml file.

I was using as below:

```
trigger:
   tags:
    include:
    - '*'
   branches:
    include:
      - ctl-sw-v01.11.01-vbeta 

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  isBranch:  $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/head/~ /^ctl-sw-v\d+\.\d+.\d+(-vbeta)?$/')]

jobs:
  - job: A
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isBranch, 'true'))
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "hello"
  - job: B
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "howdy"
```

The job A is being skipped continuously, I checked my regex, it produces a match.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use regular expressions in the startsWith expression.

A solution would be to create a separate step (in a job before job A) where you evaluate the variable isBranch with a script. This creates more code, but the benefit is that you can independently test the regex in the future which might save maintenance cost in the long run.

Moreover, `condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isBranch, 'true'))` booleans are written simply as `True`, not `'true'`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to call a script to set a variable please.

Comment: From Microsoft documentation: - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]secondValue", see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Comment: Ok.
```
    steps:
    #! set IS_RELEASE_BRANCH if branch name matches the regular expression"
    - bash: |
        echo "Checking SourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)"
        echo "$(Build.SourceBranch)" | grep -E 'ind-efd/v[[:digit:].]+_dev'
        if (( $? == 0 )) ; then
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IS_RELEASE_BRANCH]true"
            echo "IS_RELEASE_BRANCH: true"
        else
            echo "IS_RELEASE_BRANCH: false"
        fi
```
then use a condition in my task:
```
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.IS_RELEASE_BRANCH, 'true'))
```

Answer (score 2):

As Bast said, it is not supported to use regular expressions as part of condition expressions in Azure DevOps.

In addition,

**The branches should begins with `refs/heads/`, but you are using `refs/head/`.**

To avoid mistake like this, I suggest you to use `Build.SourceBranchName` instead of `Build.SourceBranch`. `Build.SourceBranchName` ignores the file structure of the branch and just search for the branch name.

Here is the example:

```
variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'

variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'
```

Comment: ok, and one other question, cant we use wildcards? `variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'ctl-sw*' `?

Comment: @RPK You can use `startsWith`, for example: `startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'ctl-sw')`

Comment: If I have a branch with `/` chars in it then only the last field (basename) is returned with `Build.SourceBranchName`.
e.g. branch name = `release/v1.2.3` => Build.SourceBranchName = `v1.2.3`