# Azure DevOps Pipeline branch name matching

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps Pipeline with the following yaml snippet.

I want to only trigger a build on development branches with branch names that match versions A.B.C or optional sub-versions (but only with numbers and dots, not with any alpha characters).

Examples:

- myproject/v3.5.2_dev
- myproject/v3.5.2.1_dev
- myproject/v4.9.7.1.2_dev

The following pipepline yaml file does not seem to automatically trigger when I push changes.  Is there something wrong with the mathcing?

Can I use extended globbing in the branch include filter?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops

```yaml
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    # - myproject/*
    # only trigger for `myproject/vX.Y.Z_dev` branches (optionally vA.B.C.D... too)
    - myproject/v+([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9])*([0-9.])_dev
  paths:
    exclude:
    - '**/*.md'
```

Comment: The [docs about branch filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#branch-filters) say: "If your branch filters aren't working, try using the prefix refs/heads/. For example, use `refs/heads/releases/old*` instead of `releases/old*`" Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with - setting a variable via a bash script and checking the condition in my task.

```yaml
variables:
  IS_RELEASE_BRANCH: false
```

```yaml
    steps:
    #! set IS_RELEASE_BRANCH if branch name matches the regular expression"
    - bash: |
        echo "Checking SourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)"
        echo "$(Build.SourceBranch)" | grep -E 'ind-efd/v[[:digit:].]+_dev'
        if (( $? == 0 )) ; then
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IS_RELEASE_BRANCH]true"
            echo "IS_RELEASE_BRANCH: true"
        else
            echo "IS_RELEASE_BRANCH: false"
        fi
```

```yaml
    - task: Foo@1
      displayName: Bar
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.IS_RELEASE_BRANCH, 'true'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73528669/triggering-jobs-with-specific-branch-names-pattern-in-azure-devops), regular expression in branch filters are not supported in Azure DevOps as of now. Alternatively you can use conditions with expressions like [`startsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#startswith) and [`endsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#endswith) to evaluate on `job` or `step` level

GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/149

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.  I'm sure `startsWith` and `endsWith` would suffice for simple situations, but quickly becomes ugly with anything moderately complex.  I might try the external script to do the evaluation and assign it to a variable trick.  Still ugly, but probably better than `startsWith` and `endsWith`.

Comment: Yes absolutely, it will get ugly but I believe till Azure DevOps doesn't add this feature this would be the workaround

Comment: I ended up using the "set variable via bash" trick.  See my answer.